# Plotting list of lists in a same graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested-lists

I am trying to plot `(x,y)` where as `y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

Say, `len(x) = len(y[1]) = len(y[2])`..
The length of the y is decided by the User input. I want to plot multiple plots of y in the same graph i.e, `(x, y[1],y[2],y[3],...)`. When I tried using loop it says `dimension error`.

I also tried: `plt.plot(x,y[i] for i in range(1,len(y)))`

How do I plot ? Please help.

```
for i in range(1,len(y)):
    plt.plot(x,y[i],label = 'id %s'%i)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You have an indentation error in the plot command. You are also starting the indexing from 1. {range (1,...) instead of range(0,...) ). I am assuming that is intentional. The code should work nonetheless. Kindly let us know the error you are facing

Comment: What are the x values? Any samples?

Comment: X=[1,2,3]. @Nikhil I am getting dimension error while plotting

Comment: I also tried ax=plt.subplot (111) and yet I get different plots for different Y's

Comment: Please check my solution below @sivasudhan

Comment: Thanks Sreejith. I figured out my mistake.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming some sample values for x, below is the code that could give you the desired output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.title("A test graph")
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    plt.plot(x,[pt[i] for pt in y],label = 'id %s'%i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Assumptions: `x` and any element in `y` are of the same length.
The idea is reading element by element so as to construct the list `(x,y[0]'s)`, `(x,y[1]'s)` and `(x,y[n]'s`.

Edited: Adapt the code if `y` contains more lists.

Below is the plot I get for this case:
[image: Sample plot]

Comment: One improvement that would adapt y values with more than 3 lists (e.g y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]] ), is to set the range in the for loop as "for i in range(len(y[0])):"

Comment: When i execute your code i get: ‘list’ object has no attribute ‘tolist’

Answer (score 10):

Use a for loop to generate the plots and use the `.show()` method after the for loop.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 for impacts in impactData:
     timefilteredForce = plt.plot(impacts)
     timefilteredForce = plt.xlabel('points')
     timefilteredForce = plt.ylabel('Force')

 plt.show()
```

impactData is a list of lists.

[image: Here's the plot this code generated.]

Comment: Thanks for this code! A minor point of correction, its `pyplt.plot(impacts` not `pyplt.plt`. cheers!

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I updated the import to match the standard plt call.