# Plotting multiple lists from a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of 78 lists, each with 1250 elements. I'm trying to plot them all on the same graph, but I'm running into an error. I'm probably missing something small, but I'm having trouble spotting it.

I adapted code from [Plotting list of lists in a same graph in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073322/plotting-list-of-lists-in-a-same-graph-in-python) which ran on it's own when I tried it, but isn't working when I use my own data.

My code:

```
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    plt.plot(freqs,[pt[i] for pt in y])
```

where y is my list of 78 lists each with 1250 elements, and freqs is a list of 1250 elements. The error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1250,) and (78,)
```

I can tell it's trying to plot the main list y instead of the elements inside of it, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Take it one step at a time. Try printing `y`. Is it the type/shape/length you expect it to be? If so, then try printing `y[0]`, is that the size you are expecting?

Comment: Yup! I printed both when I was trying to figure out exactly what was going on. y[0] is 1250 elements, y is 78 elements. I can average the list y into one 1250 element list and plot/print that, but y itself is too large to print. I can also print/plot any individual element from y[].

Comment: Hm, instead I did the following: ```for i in range(len(y)): plt.plot(freqs,y[i])``` and it seems to be working.