# how to plot a nested list(x) versus y

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I wanna scatter plot a nested list of numbers verus a list. How would I do that? For like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [[0], [1, 11, 4], [1, 11, 4, 3, 9, 6], [1, 11, 4, 3, 9, 6, 2, 12, 8]]
```

I found this, can I use this code and How would I

[Plotting list of lists in a same graph in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073322/plotting-list-of-lists-in-a-same-graph-in-python)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.title("A test graph")
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    plt.plot(x,[pt[i] for pt in y],label = 'id %s'%i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

write the code, so that he would be valid for my x and y.
Thanks

Comment: The sublists in y have to be the same length as x to make this work.

Comment: Is it in any other form possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy's `np.repeat` to repeat the x's to associate them with the y's:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [[0], [1, 11, 4], [1, 11, 4, 3, 9, 6], [1, 11, 4, 3, 9, 6, 2, 12, 8]]

for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    plt.scatter(np.repeat(xi, len(yi)), yi, color='purple')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

With list comprehension, it can even be written as one line:

```py
plt.scatter(np.repeat(x, [len(yi) for yi in y]), [i for yi in y for i in yi])
```